# Can you make conversion operators disambiguate between types?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Take this code:

```
struct Foo {
    operator char() {
        return '1';
    }
    operator std::string() {
        return "0";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string name;
    Foo foo;
    name = Foo(); //error: '=' is ambiguous
}
```

I think the assignment is ambiguous because `std::string` has an assignment operator taking `char`. Is it possible to make `Foo` assignments to `std::string` prefer `std::string's` copy constructor taking `std::string`? Could you also do the same thing with other types when these ambiguities occur?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible without an explicit conversion (using e.g. `static_cast<std::string>(Foo())`)

Comment: Opinion -- The problem with all of this is that in a non-trivial program, it will be very hard, if not near impossible to know exactly when and where the conversion operator will be used, thus you don't really know what code path is being taken when your program executes.  That's why the standard library has very few cases where these operators are utilized, and instead have functions like `to_string()`, `to_ulong()`, `c_str()`, etc.

Comment: No, the left part of the assignment doesn't participate in the template type resolutions on the right side.

Comment: `name = 'x';` and `name = "y"s;` are valid, so when you have a `Foo()` how do **you** want to disambiguate between which one should be used?

Comment: Unfortunately no, C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: @Eljay As I said, I would want the copy constructor taking std::string to be picked.

Comment: @237K implicit conversion functions (i.e. `operator T()`) are an exception to that general rule.

Comment: Make one conversion operator `explicit`.

Comment: Then you'll need to edit your compiler's `basic_string` and make the one constructor `explicit` that you do not want to participate in implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make Foo assignments to std::string prefer std::string's copy constructor taking std::string?

No, you would need to specify the type explicitly:

```
name = static_cast<std::string>(Foo());
```

However, `std::string` has an `assign` member function with the equivalent effect as `=`, but without the problematic overload:

```
name.assign(Foo());
```

> Could you also do the same thing with other types when these ambiguities occur?

In general you need to be explicit about the type you want as I show above. In certain scenarios there may be other, simpler, workarounds.

Also, all of these issues appear only because the conversion functions are not `explicit`. Consider whether it is really reasonable to have implicit conversions to both `char` and `std::string`. Multiple, especially implicit, conversion functions can easily cause other overload resolution issues as well. Generally being explicit about conversions is the safer approach.